# Loading JavaScript files in SPAs in sequential order that both depend on each other and the page they are associated with

Tags: javascript, jquery, single-page-application

I am in the process of building a Single Page Application (SPA), but I got stuck on handling JavaScript files across different parts of my SPA.

In my SPA, I load pages dynamically using jQuery's [.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/) method. The issue I've run into is that some pages require multiple JavaScript files that are dependant on each other and the page, so I must import them in sequential order once the page has been fetched and inserted into the DOM. To clarify, what I mean by JS files that depend on the page is that they contain code like selecting elements by Id, making them tied to the page.

To import these scripts in order, I use the *defer* attribute, like this:

**file.html**

```
<!-- Contents of this file that will be dynamically loaded into the SPA -->

<script defer src="/js/script_1.js"></script>
<script defer src="/js/script_2.js"></script>
<script defer src="/js/script_3.js"></script>
<script defer src="/js/script_4.js"></script>
<script defer src="/js/script_5.js"></script>
```

**index.js** (This is a stripped-down version of my original script which obviously includes caching, error handling, etc.)

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/file.html',
    success: function (data) {
        $('#main-container').html(data);
    }
});
```

The **file.html** file is successfully inserted into the DOM, but it looks like none of the JavaScript files are fetched. In fact, it seems like nothing inside the `<script></script>` tags are executed.

I've tried wrapping each JavaScript file in a function and calling them in the right order in **file.html**, but that didn't work either.

How should I approach this problem? Should I reevaluate my design?

Comment: Unrelated to this specific problem—I’d reconsider your design. It’s likely there’s little to be gained by individually loading an arbitrary number of JS files

Comment: @Dave Newton Yes, that's true. However, I like to keep my code clean and organized into different components and files. Furthermore, including one big file would only solve half of the problem.

Comment: How code exists during development is orthogonal to how it's delivered to the client.

Comment: @Dave Newton - I agree; however, above all, the problem of loading JavaScript files that dependent on a dynamically loaded page persists.

Comment: If you delivered a single JS file, only re-rendered content DOM, and tied page code runs to its loading event there's no problem. That said, reinventing SPA frameworks is also likely more trouble than it's worth. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

you can select all loaded scripts and execute them by eval()

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/file.html',
    success: function (data) {
        $('#main-container').html(data);
        $('#main-container script').each(function (index, element) { 
            if (!element.attr('has-run') || element.attr('has-run') != 'true') {                
                eval(element.innerHTML); 
                element.attr('has-run', 'true')
             }
         }
});
```

Comment: This partially works. It loads the JavaScript files fine, but when I navigate away to another page within the SPA then come back to the previous page, all JavaScript files are executed again, causing some issues. I know this is not because of your script, but do you have any suggestions on how to prevent these JS files from getting executed each time I come back to that specific page (without reloading)?

Comment: @Looky1173 - I updated my answer with a possible solution to that...

Comment: @JohnTyler - I don't think that was the problem. Since I have a caching script, each `eval()` only runs once. However, some JavaScript seems to be running itself automatically each time I revisit the specific page.

Comment: Okay, I managed to solve the problem by adding an `if` statement to each JS file to check they are on the right page, and if yes, execute. It somehow worked! :-)